# Wait for NSThread

Tags: iphone, winapi, ipad, ios

I have a many NSThreads, and I want to sleep during the time when they are working. How can I do it? Is there analogue of WinApi functions WaitForSingleObject/WaitForMultipleObjects in iOS SDK?

Answer (score 6):

There are quite a few ways, but my primary suggestion would be to look into using libdispatch.

Instead of spawning NSThreads do:

```
dispatch_group_t group = dispatch_group_create();
dispatch_group_async(group, dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    /* work to do in a thread goes here */
});
/* repeat for other threads */
dispatch_group_wait(group, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER); //wait for all the async tasks in the group to complete
```

See http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/dispatch_group_async.3.html for documentation.

An alternative would be to use a semaphore, either posix or dispatch ( http://www.csc.villanova.edu/~mdamian/threads/posixsem.html has some information, as does http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationQueues/OperationQueues.html).

(edited to add one more alternative):

This will also work nicely if all your threads are doing essentially the same work (i.e. splitting up a task rather than doing a bunch of different tasks), and is much simpler:

```
dispatch_apply(count, dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^(size_t i){
 doWork(someData, i);
});
```

Comment: But I've already written so much code using NSThread! Is there some way with NSThreads?

Comment: Are there semaphores in iOS SDK?

Comment: The full POSIX threads API is available. Failing that, the best Cocoa object would probably be an NSConditionLock.

Comment: You can check what's available by looking at the header file or the documentation... I strongly suggest reading Apple's concurrency programming guide before proceeding; this is pretty basic stuff.

Answer (score 0):

It really sounds like you should re-think your app's architecture.  Having many threads, especially on iOS, is pretty much guaranteed to be slower and, most definitely, buggier than a simpler design.

On iOS, there is only one core and bus bandwidth is exceedingly limited.

You would be far better off to use the higher level system provided concurrency tools (NSOperation, dispatch, and any of the asynchronous APIs) wherever possible.